# wwwoffle alternative?

Tags: linux, proxy, web

I'm looking for a caching proxy server that will allow me to browse visited sites while being off-line.

I'm a frequent flyer and when working on something on a plane, I find it difficult not to have access to some documentation content that I visited earlier.

In the past (like 2011) I used wwwoffle and it worked well, but it's not being actively developed since 2012 (except a maintenance release in 2016) and it's no longer packaged for Ubuntu.

Any good recommendations?

Comment: Wow, I haven't come across [`wwwoffle`](https://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/) for years! Have you the skills to install an application outside of package management? Usually such applications would land either under `/usr/local` or `/opt`, depending on your preference. In either case they are well out of the way of package management.

Comment: This is 2018. I suggest your requirements now include caching HTTPS pages, which is a significant technical difficulty. Have you tried Firefox's "Work offline" feature?  Maybe see also Firefox about:config, setting `browser.cache.disk.capacity` (I think it is measured in kilobytes).

Comment: Yes, I tried "work offline" but it works for a day. After that it only results in error page telling me... that I'm in offline mode...